# App refused to connect (NodeJs & Express)

Tags: node.js, express, permissions, shopify, shopify-app

I've created an app in the Partners panel, and I followed [this documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-express) (using Nodejs and Express).

I can get the JSON format for the products' object without any problem. However,  when I add to the scopes variable "read_price_rules" I get this error message: "express-example-app refused to connect."

Is this issue caused by the app's permissions?

My app can: Read products, variants, and collections.

**Here is the index.js file:**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cookie = require('cookie');
const nonce = require('nonce')();
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request-promise');

const apiKey = process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY;
const apiSecret = process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET;
const scopes = 'read_products,read_price_rules';
const forwardingAddress = "https://53b16008.ngrok.io";

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

app.get('/shopify', (req, res) => {
    const shop = req.query.shop;
    if (shop) {
      const state = nonce();
      const redirectUri = forwardingAddress + '/shopify/callback';
      const installUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=' + apiKey + '&scope=' + scopes + '&state=' + state + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri;

      res.cookie('state', state);
      res.redirect(installUrl);
    } 
    else { return res.status(400).send('Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request'); }
});

app.get('/shopify/callback', (req, res) => {
  const { shop, hmac, code, state } = req.query;
  const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state;

  if (state !== stateCookie) { return res.status(403).send('Request origin cannot be verified'); }

  if (shop && hmac && code) {
    // DONE: Validate request is from Shopify
    const map = Object.assign({}, req.query);
    delete map['signature'];
    delete map['hmac'];
    const message = querystring.stringify(map);
    const providedHmac = Buffer.from(hmac, 'utf-8');
    const generatedHash = Buffer.from(crypto.createHmac('sha256', apiSecret).update(message).digest('hex'), 'utf-8');
    let hashEquals = false;

    try { hashEquals = crypto.timingSafeEqual(generatedHash, providedHmac) }
    catch (e) { hashEquals = false; };

    if (!hashEquals) { return res.status(400).send('HMAC validation failed'); }

    // DONE: Exchange temporary code for a permanent access token
    const accessTokenRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/oauth/access_token';
    const accessTokenPayload = {
      client_id: apiKey,
      client_secret: apiSecret,
      code,
    };

    request.post(accessTokenRequestUrl, { json: accessTokenPayload })
    .then((accessTokenResponse) => {
      const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
      // DONE: Use access token to make API call to 'shop' endpoint
      const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/api/2019-04/discount_codes/lookup.json?code=20OFF';
      const shopRequestHeaders = { 'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken, };

      request.get(shopRequestUrl, { headers: shopRequestHeaders })
      .then((shopResponse) => {
        res.status(200).end(shopResponse);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description);
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description);
    });

  } else {
    res.status(400).send('Required parameters missing');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just had to reinstall the app after adding an extra scope in the index.js file.